# For postgres wait_event: relation, how do I find the relation?

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to detach a partition, but the query always is locked with a `wait_event` of `relation`

```
ALTER TABLE responses_partition DETACH PARTITION part_responses_2016_09;
```

What is a good method for me to determine the relation that is locking my query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the easiest way to determine locking queries is to run the pg_activity tool. It nicely shows blocking and waiting queries on 2 and 3 tab.

You can also consider browsing the pg_stat_activity table.

```
SELECT blocked_locks.pid     AS blocked_pid,
     blocked_activity.usename  AS blocked_user,
     blocking_locks.pid     AS blocking_pid,
     blocking_activity.usename AS blocking_user,
     blocked_activity.query    AS blocked_statement,
     blocking_activity.query   AS current_statement_in_blocking_process,
     blocked_activity.application_name AS blocked_application,
     blocking_activity.application_name AS blocking_application
FROM  pg_catalog.pg_locks         blocked_locks
JOIN pg_catalog.pg_stat_activity blocked_activity  ON 
blocked_activity.pid = blocked_locks.pid
JOIN pg_catalog.pg_locks         blocking_locks 
    ON blocking_locks.locktype = blocked_locks.locktype
    AND blocking_locks.DATABASE IS NOT DISTINCT FROM 
    blocked_locks.DATABASE
    AND blocking_locks.relation IS NOT DISTINCT FROM 
blocked_locks.relation
    AND blocking_locks.page IS NOT DISTINCT FROM blocked_locks.page
    AND blocking_locks.tuple IS NOT DISTINCT FROM blocked_locks.tuple
    AND blocking_locks.virtualxid IS NOT DISTINCT FROM blocked_locks.virtualxid
    AND blocking_locks.transactionid IS NOT DISTINCT FROM blocked_locks.transactionid
    AND blocking_locks.classid IS NOT DISTINCT FROM blocked_locks.classid
    AND blocking_locks.objid IS NOT DISTINCT FROM blocked_locks.objid
    AND blocking_locks.objsubid IS NOT DISTINCT FROM blocked_locks.objsubid
    AND blocking_locks.pid != blocked_locks.pid

    JOIN pg_catalog.pg_stat_activity blocking_activity ON blocking_activity.pid = blocking_locks.pid
    WHERE NOT blocked_locks.GRANTED;
```

You can find more details here: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Lock_Monitoring